# Como unir uma string a uma variável do tipo BYTE path[]

Tags: c

Gente, minha dúvida é como colocar a string1 advinda de uma função  `strcat(string1,string3);` dentro de uma string de pegar nome do usuário do windows de código:`system("reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v NOME_DO_SEU_PROGRAMA /d $string1");`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{

//pegando usuario do windows

//WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI GetUserNameA (LPSTR,PDWORD);

//WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI GetUserNameW(LPWSTR,PDWORD);

char acUserName[100];
char destino11[100];
DWORD nUserName = sizeof(acUserName);
char destino[200];
if (GetUserName(acUserName, &nUserName)) {


}   



//movendo 


    int ret;
    char oldname[] = "config/config.exe";
    char string1[] = "C:\\Users\\";
    strcat(string1,acUserName);
    char string3[] = "\\Searches\\config.exe";
    strcat(string1,string3);


  ret = rename(oldname, string1);

   if(ret == 0) {
      printf("File renamed successfully");
   } else {
      printf("Error: unable to rename the file");
   }




//ADICIONAR REGISTRO AQUI AQUI COMO COLOCAR A VARIAVEL STRING1 AI DENTRO DO SYSTEM???

system("reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v NOME_DO_SEU_PROGRAMA /d $string1");






    return 0;
    system("pause");     

}
```

Comment: gente? alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: se você já tem as duas strings prontas, qual a dificuldade em utilizar o strcpy para copiar e o strcat para concatenar?

Answer (score 0):

Em C você vai precisar criar um array de char que seja do tamanho das duas strings para poder concatenar.
Da uma olhada nesse exemplo.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char string1[] = "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v NOME_DO_SEU_PROGRAMA /d ";
    char string2[] = "Qualquer coisa que você quiser aqui";
    //Cria a stringTemp que tem que ser do tamanho da string1 + string2;
    char stringTemp[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)];
    //Joga o conteúdo da string1 em stringTemp
    strcpy(stringTemp,string1);
    //Joga o conteudo da string2 no FINAL da stringTemp, concatenando as duas
    strcat(stringTemp,string2);

    printf("%s",stringTemp);
    //Aqui você pode chamar assim:
   //system(stringTemp);
 return 0;
}
```

Você pode testar esse código acima [aqui](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/C-teste).

Comment: Agora como jogar a stringTemp dentro da system("reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v NOME_DO_SEU_PROGRAMA /d $stringTempNAOFUNCIONAAQUI

Comment: O que você fez da parte de concatenação eu fiz lá encima usando strcat, estou perguntando como botar a variável do tipo char dentro da função system.

Comment: Você vai passar a string tempo aí dentro, você concatena tudo o que precisa e passa só ela na função, assim system(stringTempo);

Comment: Se você testar isso vai ver que não vai funcionar, estou falando de colocar dentro disso:system("reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v NOME_DO_SEU_PROGRAMA /d STRINGTEMPO");

Comment: @MayaraRabelo , da uma olhada, eu editei para deixar mais próximo da sua realidade. Claro que na parte onde eu coloquei o system() comentado você descomenta no seu código.

Comment: Na hora de executar o system deu sintexe inválida

Comment: @MayaraRabelo da um printf em como ficou o seu comando e poste, provavelmente esta com algum parâmetro errado. Verifique se deu espaço também no final da string para quando concatenar não acabe "colando" as 2

Comment: quero fazer assim: char string11[] = "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v NOME_DO_SEU_PROGRAMA /d ";
    char string22[] = string1;

Comment: Por que isso não funciona? char string22[] = string1;

Comment: no php da certinho

Comment: @MayaraRabelo Em C ele não aceita você inicializar um vetor de string com outro vetor, por isso existe as funções strcat e strcpy para concatenar e copiar os valores. Lembrando sempre que o vetor que vai receber os dados do outro vetor deve ter tamanho suficiente para isso, por isso a questão de usar um terceiro vetor que é criado com o tamanho do primeiro + o tamanho do segundo, e então concatenar tudo nele.